# How to render "<from>-<to>" if <to>is in a right-to-left script?

Tags: bidi

There is a volume of the Appendix of the amazing [Print Wikipedia](http://printwikipedia.com/) publication which lists contributors to Wikipedia. The first contributor listed in this particular volume is "Xholierthanthou".
The last contributor's name is in Arabic "محمّدمحمّدمحمّدمحمّدمحمّدمحمّد".

My question is how the volume name should be rendered when it is all on one line, like "Xholierthanthou - محمّدمحمّدمحمّدمحمّدمحمّدمحمّد"? Should the Arabic name be on the right, or on the left? This is where more intricacies of [Bi-directional text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text) come into play.

I've captured some screenshots of various Twitter pages which show some of the surprising options in this issue report on the Github project for Printwikipedia:

[Volume naming in the face of bidirectional text · Issue #12 · mandiberg/printwikipedia](https://github.com/mandiberg/printwikipedia/issues/12)

*(Forgive me if this is not the right site for this question.  But it seems like the answer would at least be of interest here, and I found more references to bidirectional text display here than other Stack Exchange sites.  If there's a better site, feel free to move it.)*